# Do I need to tell the USA I changed my name?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta

I changed my name recently (First and last due to simply disliking my birthname) and received my new passport.

I visited the USA last year in December with my old passport and old name, do I need to tell them that I've changed it?

I've already applied and been approved for my new Esta.

Oh! I also don't use my old name for anything. I only use my new name (The one on my new passport)

So in short  my question is, does/will it matter?

Comment: You already got an ESTA under your new name why do you think anything else is necessary? If the CBP wanted to know whether you have visited the US under an old name, believe me, they'd ask on the ESTA form. One thing for sure, the CBP (and in general, similar immigration authorities) are never shy to ask about whatever might interest them often things ordinary people find completely baffling.

Comment: I guess that's true! I guess I'm just paranoid? I saved up a lot of money for my trip so the idea of being turned away is scary. I'm going to be staying for 86 days (I'm not a frequent traveler or anything, I'm just a 19 year old college student and the whole reason I'm staying for so long is because I start college this September and I'll be way too busy next year to have any real vacations outside of the UK) If I'm asked if I've been to the USA before (Which i have) do I say yes? what if they ask why it isn't in my current passport? Can I just say I got a new passport since then? (Thx 4 help

Comment: @chx's point said it all, unless you were banned from entering the US after your last visit with your old name. That's a different story.

Comment: If you're asked questions, you should answer them honestly. They'll have your biometrics on file (assuming you've been to the US before in the last decade or so, which I figure you have since you have an old ESTA) so they'll know you're the same person. If you lie and tell them you haven't been to the US before, they will know and then you really will have a problem. If they ask, just tell them you changed your name and were issued a new passport. You could carry a copy of the paperwork from your name change to document this if it makes you happy. This is not an uncommon situation.

Comment: I changed my name using deedpoll, so do you mean I should bring that? I do still have possession of my old passport (It's had it's corners cut off making it unusable, I just have it stashed in my draw since it's sort of a memento of my first ever visit to the USA) I changed my name entirely and apart of me is worried they'll want a background check? IDK I'm probably just too nervous but after reading all these custom horror stories it's hard not to be! (Thanks for the help so far!)

Comment: Why would they want a background check? Just relax. Bring your deed poll and your old passport.  It's likely you won't need them, but it sounds like having them will help you relax.

Answer (score 3):

It's no problem to change your name. People do this all the time.

You might be asked briefly about it, but if you don't have any adverse immigration history, it should not be an issue. To be sure, you can bring your old passport and deed poll.

The most important thing to do with immigration is to relax and answer any questions honestly but briefly. You don't need to go into details on any question unless asked specifically.